# Syncing app data across multiple android devices

Tags: android, mobile, cloud

Currently new to android development and i'm developing my first app. How can I sync all data for the same user across multiple devices (i.e. Such that he/she can have the app running on all his/her android devices where the app is installed), using cloud?

Comment: what i understood from ur question is u want the user data to be synced if user is logged in more then one device correct me if i am wrong

Comment: what is the solution that you found?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to have cloud storage to which you will synchronise your application data.
You need to consider 2 things

- Cloud Storage Service (e.g :Drop box,Google App Engine)
- Implementation for bi-directional data synchronisation (Check out Android Sync Adapters http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/index.html)